# Incorrect display of the enter\registration link

Tags: html, css, wordpress, flexbox

In the file `C:\OSPanel\OpenServer\domains\shop.ru\wp-content\themes\twentytwenty\header.php` added lines from 85th to 100th

```html
<div class="header-navigation-authblock">
    <a href="#">
        <span>
            <span>
                <div class="header-navigation-authblockimage">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/greenicon.jpg" width="70px" height="70px" class="entrylink3"></img>
                </div>
            </span>
            <span>
                <div class="header-navigation-authblocklabel">
                    Войти
                </div>
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

and added to the file `C:OSPanel\OpenServer\domains\shop.ru\wp-content\themes\twentytwenty\style.css` lines from 6491 to 6514

```html
.header-navigation-authblock {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

//**.header-navigation-authblock,*// .header-navigation-authblockimage, .header-navigation-authblocklabel {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-navigation-authblock:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.header-navigation-authblockimage, .header-navigation-authblocklabel {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

But as a result I get a screenshot

[Two-line login\registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6bSy.png)

but must be on one line because of the `span` and `display: flex` tags. How do you achieve the desired display?

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```html
<div class="header-navigation-authblock">
    <a href="#">
        <span>
            <span>
                <div class="header-navigation-authblockimage">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/greenicon.jpg' ?>" width="70px" height="70px" class="entrylink3"></img>
                </div>
            </span>
            <span>
                <div class="header-navigation-authblocklabel">
                    Войти
                </div>
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```